# Adding audio to a java program

Tags: java, audio

I'd like to add both, Looping music in the background to a game I made, as well as sounds that play when certain events take place. I've searched Google but the only results I've come up with are how to implement them to an Applet, or an outdated version.

Comment: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: I've tried all of that within the guide. Read my question before you answer. "I've searched Google" And I've tried plenty of other methods to find the answer. Don't jump to conclusions so quickly.

Comment: You might want to list the things you tried and why they didn't work...

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind linking native code, you could use several Java libraries that provide bindings to native game/sound libraries. For example: [Java binding to SDL](http://sdljava.sourceforge.net/), [LightWeight Java Game Library](http://lwjgl.org/) or [JogAmp](http://jogamp.org/) (the latter two use [OpenAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAL) API).

You could also use Java's [javax.sound package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/index.html) which is integrated into JDK/JRE, but from my experience, it's not very easy to work with.